# ISO installs grub to /dev/sda instead of sdb (disk)

Tags: boot, 18.04, grub2

I am installing a Ubuntu ISO (from USB [burnt with Rufus]), which installs fine but `grub` is installed on `/dev/sda` instead of `sdb`, so the system becomes like
*live boot* - have to always keep USB plugged in!
If I run `grub-install /dev/sdb` after installation, then from next reboot it works
fine!
Is there anyway to tell grub to install on `dev/sdb` or disk ?

P.S. the device has UEFI, but I am using Legacy bios if that matters.

Comment: Usually the main internal hard drive is label sda( not always).  sdb should be your USB or a secondary internal/external drive.  Check with disks or gparted which label goes with which disk/drive and where you have ubuntu installed.

Comment: You can install grub to a sdb with `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`

Comment: @crip659, I have a device wherein disk is sdb, so how can I fix this at ISO installation time?

Comment: @Knud Larsen, I want to run this unattended at ISO installation time. How do I embed this command? In kickseed?

Comment: @vyom is that disk where you installed ubuntu(not USB with ISO).  If so then should only need command that Knud gave.  During installation there is option near bottom of page where you make/adjust your partitions asking where to install grub.

Comment: @crip659,  Yes, I installed ubuntu on the disk (which was `/dev/sdb`).I am not getting that grub option! :-/ maybe due to a bad kickseed, not sure.  Is there any way to say that the disk should be `/dev/sda` always ?

Comment: Are you using the option 'something else' for installing?

Comment: @crip659, I think there is some option in the kickseed file which is making partman pick some option by default! I am checking that, noob on ISO customization! :-/